# Activity Feeds "Leads I follow" view breaking CRM 2011 Solution Import

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm working on exporting a managed solution from a dev environment into another, clean environment. However, the solution will not import, due to dependency violations with the "Contacts Being Followed", "Contacts I follow", "Leads Being Followed", and "Leads I follow" views. Depending on how I tinker with the solution, the error can range from

"There was an error calculating the dependency: Error in Saved Query with ID ..."

to

"A managed solution cannot overwrite the SavedQuery component with Id=3a282da1-5d90-e011-95ae-00155d9cfa03 which has an unmanaged base instance.  The most likely scenario for this error is that an unmanaged solution has installed a new unmanaged SavedQuery component on the target system, and now a managed solution from the same publisher is trying to install that same SavedQuery component as managed.  This will cause an invalid layering of solutions on the target system and is not allowed."

But in either case, the culprit is one of those views relating to activity feeds. The Lead and Contact and Campaign Activity are the only out of the box entities in this solution. How do I get rid of this dependency?

The source org is an on-premise install, so Activity Feeds were manually deployed via the marketplace download. I've tried to import the managed solution export into both online and on-premise orgs.

If I remove the 4 views above from the customization.xml file that the export produces, I can then successfully import the solution. The views are, or course, still in the target system after import, because they're system views that come with Activity Feeds. But I'm not comfortable with that being the real solution, since I know it's unsupported to modify the XML directly in solution export.

I found a temporary fix when I removed the views from the customizations.xml file of an export of the unmanaged solution, and imported that solution into a fresh org. Then, I exported that solution (call it solution 2) as an unmanaged solution, deleted the original unmanaged solution in the environment where I originally built the solution. Then I imported solution 2 into the original environment again. When I exported this solution, I could then import it into other orgs. But when we updated some components in the dev org and tried to export to test, the error was back.

Anyone know what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was directed to the answer here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2012/01/26/activity-feeds-solution-amp-development-environment.aspx

Apparently, in a dev environment, you need to leave Activity Feeds unconfigured. I'm having errors "uconfiguring" in my own environment, but think this is definitely the answer to the question I posed above.